# Pytest test case fails but gives correct result when run from terminal with same input

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest

I am new to pytest and using it for unit testing my python code.
I have a class called `ProblemSorting` in the file called `difficulty`. There is a method `get_difficulty_order()` in the class.

Below is the unit test that I have written to test the method:

```
import pytest
from difficulty import ProblemSorting

@pytest.mark.parametrize("num_of_problems, num_of_subtasks, problems, result",
                         [
                             pytest.param(3, 3, [[16, 24, 60],
                                                 [498, 861, 589],
                                                 [14, 24, 62],
                                                 [72, 557, 819],
                                                 [16, 15, 69],
                                                 [435, 779, 232]], [2, 1, 3]),
                             pytest.param(1, 1, [[2], [5]], [1]),
                             pytest.param(0, 0, [], [])])
def test_get_difficulty_order(num_of_problems, num_of_subtasks, problems, result):
    '''hello'''
    prob_sort = ProblemSorting(num_of_problems, num_of_subtasks, problems)
    assert prob_sort.get_difficulty_order() == result
```

Now the problem is that the `2nd` test case fails. But when I remove the `1st` and the `3rd` test cases and retain the `2nd` test case it works. Even when I manually check the code with the `2nd` input it gives the expected result.

**Note:** I have also noted that no matter how many test cases it has it only succeed the first and the last test case and all in the middle fails.

**Edit:** difficulty.py
'''check'''

```
import operator

class ProblemSorting:
    '''Class implementing various methods to solve the problem
       which requires ordering of problem based on its difficulty level
    '''

    # stores the tuple (i, difficulty) where 'i' is the problem number
    # and 'difficulty' is the difficulty level associated with the 'i'th problem
    difficulty_of_problems = list()

    def __init__(self, num_of_problems, num_of_subtasks, problems):
        self.num_of_problems = num_of_problems
        self.num_of_subtasks = num_of_subtasks
        self.problems = problems
```

I don't understand what is wrong with this.
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: sounds like your function has side effects that affect subsequent calls

Comment: @PaulH how do I know and fix them? Thanks for pointing anyway. Could you please give some example of side effects?

Comment: I'd have to see the function

Comment: @PaulH I have added the code

Comment: the class attribute `difficulty_of_problems ` is continually appended to by all instances. make it a instance attribute instead (i.e., put `self.difficulty_of_problems` inside the `__init__ method`

Comment: @PaulH It worked. Thanks a lot.